# How to use ActivityResult API in fragment when Activity overrides `onActivityResult` method

Tags: android, kotlin, onactivityresult, registerforactivityresult, activity-result-api

I am using new [ActivityResultApi](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result) with ReactNavtive.

ReactActivity overrides `onActivityResult` method.

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
   mDelegate.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

My Fragment code

```
result = registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult()){
         //not getting call back here
    }
```

How can I get callback back here?

One solution I am working on is calling fragment's `onActivityResult` method from activity like this

```
class MainActivity: ReactActivity {
   ... 
   override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
    
    val fragment = supportFragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(TAG)
    
    if(fragment is LoadingFragment){
        fragment.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
    }
    
}
   ...
```

What would be the better approach? How to prevent overriding `onActivityResult` method in our Activity?

Comment: Looks like the failure to call `super.onActivityResult` in ResultActivity has been fixed in the latest release of the reactive-native library, if that's what you're using. https://github.com/facebook/react-native/commit/29249e19bd9cb4de8cb5b00edcd17f2c49d0d02c#diff-5eeea7cc5d0049418255078dfb3555cdbc3fc02e370392f4b6a31dd831720270

Comment: @Tenfour04 cool! but we can't upgrade RN at the moment.